# Proof of −(x + y) = −x − y

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Prove that −(x + y) = − x − y.

Is the following proof correct? I'm not sure about the last modification.

−(x + y) = −(x + y) + x + (-x) + y + (-y) = (x + y) + (−(x + y)) + (-x) + (-y) = (-x) + (-y) = - x - y

Comment: Welcome. That looks fine to me

Comment: It is certainly correct for *some* choice of axioms, i.e. of statements that you can assume to be correct and/or previously proven. Also you implicitly assume a few things, such as $-(x+y)=-(x+y)+0+0$ (which then you break down to $0=x+(-x)$, $0=y+(-y)$).

Comment: Depends on your axioms and you should probably state them directly and one at a time but... yes that is correct.  (But I'd provide more "words" explaining what we are doing).

Comment: Alternatively $(x+y)+(-x-y)=(y+x)+(-x-y) = y+(x-x)-y=y-y=0$.

Comment: Ex:  *why* does $-(x+y) + x+(-x) +y +(-y)$?  That needs to be broken down: $-(x+y) =-(x+y) + 0$ (by natural of additive identity) $=-(x+y)+0+0$ (ditto) $=-(x+y) + (x+(-x)) + (y+(-y))$ (by all numbers having an inverse).  We can jump to $=(x+y) +(-(x+y) +(-x)+(-y)$ as a "combination" of associativity and commutativity (I won't be that anal about it).  But then we should point out $=0 +(-x)+(-y)$ by natural of inverses and $=(-x)+(-y)$ by nature of additive identity.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone!